# Deployed react express app on google app engine Endpoints giving error message when i request url?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi

I am trying to deploy my react express app on google app engine. Everything works fine on localhost but when I deploy I get a 404 error:

I assume this could be something wrong with my handlers but i'm not to sure, help would be much appreciated.

```
Cannot GET /

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

This is what the console log says:

```
 httpRequest: {
  latency:  "0.006s"   
  referer:  "-"   
  remoteIp:  "2001:8000:11d3:ed00:4854:5aba:9f93:dd47"   
  requestMethod:  "GET"   
  requestUrl:  "/"   
  responseSize:  "139"   
  status:  404   
  userAgent:  "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36"   
 }
 insertId:  "ezhqr2g2ohjlxu"  
 jsonPayload: {
  appLatencySeconds:  "0.004"   
  httpRequest: {
   protocol:  "HTTP/1.1"    
  }
  latencySeconds:  "0.006"   
  trace:  "dd9ffc275b4f1457905cf864bf17539c"   
 }
 labels: {
  appengine.googleapis.com/instance_name:  "aef-web--form-20190524t155912-31cn"   
  appengine.googleapis.com/trace_id:  "dd9ffc275b4f1457905cf864bf17539c"   
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_id:  "1391234725058328108"   
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_name:  "a68af8bf7290"   
  compute.googleapis.com/zone:  "australia-southeast1-b"   
 }
 logName:  "confidential"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-05-26T22:36:57.374278865Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   module_id:  "web-form"    
   project_id:  "confidential"    
   version_id:  "20190524t155912"    
  }
  type:  "gae_app"   
 }
 timestamp:  "2019-05-26T22:36:54.837Z"  
 trace:  "confidential"  
}
```

and here is my yaml file:

```
service: web-form
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

automatic_scaling:
   min_num_instances: 1
   max_num_instances: 1

env_variables:
  PROJECT_ID: 'project'


handlers:
  - url: /*
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: auto

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 1.7
  disk_size_gb: 10
  volumes:
  - name: ramdisk1
    volume_type: tmpfs
    size_gb: 1
```

Comment: Without seeing your code and package.json, we can only guess. The app is returning a 404 to `GET /`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deploying react express app on google app engine Endpoints giving error message when i request url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56319471/deploying-react-express-app-on-google-app-engine-endpoints-giving-error-message)