# deploying react express app on google app engine Endpoints giving error message when i request url?

Tags: reactjs, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to deploy my react express app on google app engine. Everything works fine on localhost but when I deploy I get a 404 error:

I assume this could be something wrong with my handlers but i'm not to sure, help would be much appreciated.

Cannot GET /

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
This is what the console log says:

```
 httpRequest: {
  latency:  "0.006s"   
  referer:  "-"   
  remoteIp:  "2001:8000:11d3:ed00:4854:5aba:9f93:dd47"   
  requestMethod:  "GET"   
  requestUrl:  "/"   
  responseSize:  "139"   
  status:  404   
  userAgent:  "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36"   
 }
 insertId:  "ezhqr2g2ohjlxu"  
 jsonPayload: {
  appLatencySeconds:  "0.004"   
  httpRequest: {
   protocol:  "HTTP/1.1"    
  }
  latencySeconds:  "0.006"   
  trace:  "dd9ffc275b4f1457905cf864bf17539c"   
 }
 labels: {
  appengine.googleapis.com/instance_name:  "aef-web--form-20190524t155912-31cn"   
  appengine.googleapis.com/trace_id:  "dd9ffc275b4f1457905cf864bf17539c"   
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_id:  "1391234725058328108"   
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_name:  "a68af8bf7290"   
  compute.googleapis.com/zone:  "australia-southeast1-b"   
 }
 logName:  "confidential"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-05-26T22:36:57.374278865Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   module_id:  "web-form"    
   project_id:  "confidential"    
   version_id:  "20190524t155912"    
  }
  type:  "gae_app"   
 }
 timestamp:  "2019-05-26T22:36:54.837Z"  
 trace:  "confidential"  
}
and here is my yaml file:

service: web-form
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

automatic_scaling:
   min_num_instances: 1
   max_num_instances: 1

env_variables:
  PROJECT_ID: 'project'


handlers:
  - url: /*
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: auto

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 1.7
  disk_size_gb: 10
  volumes:
  - name: ramdisk1
    volume_type: tmpfs
    size_gb: 1
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PageOne from "./components/PageOne";
import PageTwo from "./components/PageTwo";
import PageThree from "./components/PageThree";
import PageFour from "./components/PageFour";
import PageFive from "./components/PageFive";
import PageSix from "./components/PageSix";
import { Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";

import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      generalDetails: "Text",
      fName: "Text",
      mName: "Text",
      // LName: "Text",
      gender: "Text",
    };

    this.onContentChange = this.onContentChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmitForm = this.onSubmitForm.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <PageOne handleChange={this.onContentChange} />
        <PageTwo handleChange={this.onContentChange} />
        <PageThree handleChange={this.onContentChange} />
        <PageFour handleChange={this.onContentChange} />
        <PageFive handleChange={this.onContentChange} />
        <PageSix handleChange={this.onContentChange} />

        <Button onClick={this.onSubmitForm}
        style={{
          marginLeft: 700,
        }}
        >Submit Form</Button>

        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }

  onSubmitForm = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
      generalDetails: this.state.generalDetails,
      fName: this.state.fName,
      mName: this.state.mName,
      lName: this.state.lName,
      email: this.state.email,

    };


    axios
  .post("http://localhost:3000/home", data)
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result)
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("Something went wrong. Please try again later");
  });


  };

  //end

  onContentChange(fieldname, data) {
    console.log("On Content Change", data);

    this.setState({
      [fieldname]: data
    });
  }
}

export default App;
```

server.js

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const http = require('http')
const server = http.createServer(app)
const port = 8080
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
const mailgunTransport = require('nodemailer-mailgun-transport')

// to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
  })
)


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(
    'Hello from .get /home',
    req.body.generalDetails,
    req.body.firstName,
    req.body.mName
  )
})

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  const mailgun = require("mailgun-js");

  const DOMAIN = 'sandbox89eb814ff83548cebd77c0c7d263172e.mailgun.org';
  const mg = mailgun({apiKey: 'b81454a616bb9ab79e36ebd10984f1a3-115fe3a6-26eae655'
, domain: 'sandbox89eb814ff83548cebd77c0c7d263172e.mailgun.org' });
  const message = {
    from: 'Tom <thomas.hunt@careertrackers.org.au>',
    to: 'thomas.hunt@careertrackers.org.au',
    subject: 'Registration form details',
    html:

    '<h1 style="color:red">Please find new Program orientation registrations details below</h1>' +


    '<p><strong>General Details</strong></p>' +
     '<b> General Details: </b>  ' + '' + req.body.generalDetails +
    '<br> <b>First Name: </b> ' + '' + req.body.fName +
    '<br> <b>Middle Name: </b> ' + '' + req.body.mName +
    '<br> <b>Last Name: </b> ' + '' + req.body.lName +


  };

  mg.messages().send(message, function (error, body) {
    console.log(body);
  });

  let data = [
    {
      // page one data
      generalDetails: req.body.generalDetails,
      fName: req.body.fName,
      mName: req.body.mName,
      lName: req.body.lName,
      email: req.body.email,

    }
  ]

  res.json(data)
})

app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`)
```

Package.json Reactexpress:

```
{
  "name": "reactexpress",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Starter kit for creating React and Express apps",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "cd client && npm install",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "author": "Brad Traversy",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.14.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "mailgun-js": "^0.22.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.1.1",
    "nodemailer-mailgun-transport": "^1.4.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.87.1"
  }
}
```

package.json client:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000"
}
```

Comment: In you App.js, are you still pointing to localhost:3000?

Comment: yes I am @Ashish

Comment: Then how come you will fetch data from your google app engine server. You should point you axios API to https://<whatever is your engine endpoint>/home